# mongodb $and expression must be a nonempty array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongo and I'm getting an error. Both $user_id and $this->_id are non empty (valid mongo id).

```php
$criteria = array( 
    '$and' => array( 
        array('parent_id' =>$this->_id), 
        '$or' => array(
            array('user_id' => $user_id),
            array('from_user_id' => $user_id)
        )               
    ) 
);
```

the error says

```php
$and expression must be a nonempty array
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined your array properly:

```php
$criteria = array(
  '$and' => array(
    array('parent_id' => $this->_id ),
    array('$or' => array(
      array('user_id' => $user_id ),
      array('from_user_id' => $user_id ) 
    ))
```

)
);

Try to check your structures before submitting as a query to make sure they format as you expect:

```php
echo json_encode( $criteria, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) ."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know now how to validate the structure of my query by using `json_encode` with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`